# Using list comprehension, how to take user input until a certain input/stop_word is encountered?

Tags: python, iterator, list-comprehension

I want to keep taking input from user, until the user enters a certain string, **inside a `list comprehension`**, how to achieve this?

What I need is equivalent to:

```
lst = []
stop = 'stop'

while True:
    val = input()
    if val == stop:
        break
    lst.append(val)

print('output:',lst)

# Output:
# 1
#
# hello
#
# three
#
# [1, 2, 3]
#
# stop
# output: ['1', 'hello', 'three', '[1, 2, 3]']
```

But, to reiterate, **I don't want `while`**, I would prefer a **one-liner**, something like:

```
stop = 'stop'
lst = [i for i in take_input_until(stop)]
print(lst)

# Output:
# 1
#
# hello
#
# three
#
# [1, 2, 3]
#
# stop
# output: ['1', 'hello', 'three', '[1, 2, 3]']
```

Furthermore, can this be applied to **any user defined** function, so that it can be calculated until a specific value is returned?

I have checked these questions, which did not meet my requirement:

- [How to take valid and specific number of inputs from the user using list comprehension as of the statement given below in python [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65322419/5431791)

  This deals with specific number of inputs, also the solution is based on regex parsing, which won't work here.
- [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/5431791)
  This uses while, which is the very thing I do not want. Furthermore, the motive of this question leans more towards input validation, rather than control flow.

Answer (score 1):

## [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to the rescue

Even though `iter` is mainly used with a single argument, it has a lesser known second argument, that changes how the function behaves.

From [python docs of iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

> `iter(object[, sentinel])`
>
> > ...If the second argument, sentinel, is given, then object must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call object with no arguments for each call to its **next**() method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, StopIteration will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.
> >
> > One useful application of the second form of iter() is to build a block-reader. For example, reading fixed-width blocks from a binary database file until the end of file is reached:
> >
> > ```
> > from functools import partial
> > with open('mydata.db', 'rb') as f:
> >    for block in iter(partial(f.read, 64), b''):
> >        process_block(block)
> > ```
> >
> > ---

The above example answers the second question as well. There are other ways to achieve this. In the following examples I would illustrate different ways to take input until a specific condition is met, however, this is just special case, for the second question, it's just that the function is `input`. So **all the examples below, can be made to work for any other function.**

This can be used for taking `input` until a specific input is encountered:

```
>>> STOP = 'stop'
>>> lst = list(iter(input, STOP))
# can also be written as list comprehension, 
# which would be helpful if you want to do something with the values
#>> lst = [i for i in iter(input, STOP)]

1

hello

three

[1, 2, 3]

stop

>>> print(lst)
['1', 'hello', 'three', '[1, 2, 3]']
```

Here `iter(input, STOP)` is something which is known as `callable_iterator`:

```
>>> type(iter(input, STOP))
callable_iterator
```

#### Showing input prompt

In order to show input prompts for each input, we can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> lst = [i for i in iter(partial(input, 'enter: '), 'x')]   # or list(iter(partial(input, 'enter: '), 'x'))

enter: 1

enter: 2

enter: 3

enter: x

>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']
```

#### Including the stop word

If you wanted to include the stop word in the list as well, you could use [`iterable unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) via `*` operator:

```
>>> STOP = 'x'
>>> input_with_prompt = partial(input, 'enter: ')
>>> lst = [*iter(input_with_prompt, STOP), STOP]

enter: 1

enter: 2

enter: 3

enter: x

>>> lst
['1', '2', '3', 'x']
```

**This has to be the easiest way to replace while. However, for more complex requirements, this is not very useful.**

Answer (score 0):

## `takewhile` condition is True

We can use a function in [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to check whether the input is equal to stop word, if not, keep taking input:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> STOP = 'x'
>>> lst = list(takewhile(lambda inp: inp != STOP, iter(input_with_prompt, None)))

enter: 1

enter: 2

enter: 3

enter: x

>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']
```

Here `iter(input_with_prompt, None)` will keep calling `input`, because it's `sentinel` argument will never be met, as `input` returns `str` only. This is roughly equivalent to a `while True` loop, except the values are lazily calculated.

`takewhile` will call `__next__` on the `callable_iterator` object, and apply the function on the next value, while the condition meets.

This may seem like a redundant and over complicated way of doing the same thing, however, its advantages should be apparent in following examples.

**Merits :**

1. takewhile can be used to test for **multiple stop_words**:

```
>>> lst = list(takewhile(lambda inp: inp not in ['q', 'quit', 'Q'], iter(input_with_prompt, None)))

enter: 1

enter: 2

enter: 3

enter: quit

>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']
```

2. Can be used to pass multiple values to the function, using another `iterator` type object, here is an example with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) that is used to provide different argument to `input` at each call.

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> lst = list(takewhile(
...     lambda inp: inp != STOP,
...     (input(f'enter val #{i} ("{STOP}" to quit): ') for i in count(1))
... ))

enter val #1 ("x" to quit): 1

enter val #2 ("x" to quit): 2

enter val #3 ("x" to quit): 3

enter val #4 ("x" to quit): x

>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']
```

3. Can be combined with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) or [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to stop either when `stop_word` is encountered, or number of inputs reaches a specific value.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> MAX_NUM = 5
>>> lst = list(takewhile(
...     lambda inp: inp != STOP,
...     ((input('enter : ') for _ in range(MAX_NUM))
... ))

enter : 1

enter : 2

enter : 3

enter : 4

enter : 5
>>> lst
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

# ^ Here stop word is not encountered, 
# but input stops when MAX_NUM is reached.
#---------------------------------------------------#
>>> lst = list(takewhile(
...     lambda inp: inp != STOP,
...     (input('enter : ') for _ in repeat(None, MAX_NUM)) 
... ))

enter : 1

enter : 2

enter : 3

enter : x
>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']

# ^ here stop word is encountered before MAX_NUM is reached.
```

**NOTE:** `(f() for _ in range(n))` behaves the same as `(f() for _ repeat(None, n))`, however the latter is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098860/5431791) when the when the loop variable is not needed.

4. Can be combined with [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) to get nested `list` for multiple stopwords.

```
>>> list_of_list = list(list(val) 
...      for val in starmap(
...                     iter, 
...                     [
...                         (input_with_prompt, 'q'), 
...                         (input_with_prompt, 'quit'), 
...                         (input_with_prompt, 'Q')
...                     ])
... ))

enter: 1

enter: 2

enter: q

enter: 2

enter: 3

enter: 4

enter: quit

enter: 5

enter: Q
>>> list_of_list
[['1', '2'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['5']]
```

While this might look a like a very arcane usecase, it can be especially useful for other domains, for example optimization techniques where you want to check the intermediate steps taken to reach a specific result with different hyperparameters.

**So for flexibility, `takewhile` can be used, but may be at the cost of readability.**

Answer (score 0):

#### Build your own Iterator

Another option could be making a custom [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) object.

```
class IterWithCond:
    """Continuously call a function, until a given condition is met."""

    def __init__(
        self, func, cond, include_break=False, max_num=float('inf'), args=(), kwargs={}
    ):
        self.func = func
        self.cond = cond
        self.args = args if isinstance(args, (list, tuple)) else (args,)
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.include = include_break
        self.max_num = max_num

    def __iter__(self):
        self._count = 0
        self._cond_met = False
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._cond_met or self._count >= self.max_num:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            out = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            self._cond_met = self.cond(out)
            if not self.include and self._cond_met:
                raise StopIteration
            self._count += 1
            return out
    # Following line enables functionalities like `iter(IterWithCond(*args), stop)`
    __call__ = __next__
```

You can choose what configuration you want.

- Vanila input without prompt, until `q` or `Q` is entered.

```
>>> itr_obj = IterWithCond(
    func=input,
    cond=lambda x: x.lower() == 'q',
)
>>> lst = list(itr_obj)

1

2

3

q
>>> lst
['1', '2', '3']
```

- Add prompt, include the break character

```
>>> itr_obj = IterWithCond(
    func=input,
    cond=lambda x: x.lower() == 'q',
    include_break=True,
    args='enter: '
)
>>> lst = list(itr_obj)

enter: 1

enter: 2

enter: 3

enter: q

>>> lst
['1', '2', '3', 'q']
```

- Take until the user inputs 'q'/'Q' or until the user inputs 5 numbers, don't include stop character if it is stopped by stop character.

```
>>> itr_obj = IterWithCond(
    func=input,
    cond=lambda x: x.lower() == 'q',
    args='enter: ',
    max_num=5
)
>>> lst = list(itr_obj)

enter: 1

enter: 2

enter: 3

enter: 4

enter: 5

>>> lst
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

**For flexibility and readability, this one is the best. But if it is only worthwhile if it is used multiple times throughout the program with different conditions.**